# Why does redefining string str doesn't show error?

Tags: c++

```
int N;
cin >> N;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
{
//here string is redefined per loop cycle, still no error 


    string str;
    cin >> str;


//ignore code below 

    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) 
    {
        if (j % 2 == 0)
            cout << str[j];
    }
    cout << " ";
    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) 
    {
        if (j % 2 != 0)
        {
            cout << str[j];
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: It doesn't show an error because this is legal in c++. Could you explain why you think it shouldn't be valid?

Comment: Um, excuse me, but `str` is only defined once in the code you've shown...

Comment: Why would you put a comment saying `ignore code below` instead of actually removing the irrelevant code?

Comment: It also get destroyed on closing - '}', it is new variable per iteration

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're asking why this (cut down version) is valid:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)  {
    string str;
}
```

when the string is being redefined every time through the loop.

However, that's perfectly acceptable. The lifetime of the string object extends from immediately after the semicolon following `str` to the closing brace `}`, which is part of the loop itself. Hence it effectively comes into, and goes out of, existence for every single iteration of that loop<sup>(a)</sup>.

It's no different really to the snippet:

```
{
    int xyzzy = 42; // xyzzy now exists.
}                   // and no longer exists from here on.
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Technically, using the as-if rule, it could reuse the *same* object, provided it was cleared out to an empty string each time.

Comment: *it could reuse the same object* It would have to call the destructor, so by the same object you mean the same memory block?

Comment: @Ayxan: no, I mean it doesn't even have to call the destructor at all if it doesn't want to. For `std::string`, I don't believe there is any observable behaviour that can be picked up by the user, so the "as-if" rule kicks in: "conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine". It would have to destruct for a non-built-in class but that's only because the observable behaviour exists there.